# Cannot get sum on dataview field

Tags: c#, linq

I try to get a list from a dataview containing a sum and grouped by some fields.

```
DataView view = _objManager.ACCOUNTS.DefaultView;
                    
                    // Set RowStateFilter to display the current rows.
                    view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows;

                    var res = ((DataTable)view.Table)
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(row => new { ID = row.Field<long?>("ID"), ELEM = row.Field<string>("ELEM") })
                      .Select(sel => new
                      {
                          NAME = sel.First()["NAME"],
                          ID = sel.First()["ID"],
                          IBAN = sel.First()["IBAN"],
                          BIC = sel.First()["BIC"],
                          INFO = sel.First()["INFO"],
              AMOUNT= sel.Sum(s => s.Sum()["AMOUNT"])  //doesn't work                           
                      }).ToList();
```

But the sum doesn't compile.
Do you have and idea ?
Thanks a lot in advance.
Eric

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: The error was that it cannot sum object and it missed a cast to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
AMOUNT= sel.Sum(s => s["AMOUNT"])
```

if `sel.First()["Amount"]` is a number then you can sum all the amounts via the method above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Jawad.
Your advice is the main part of the answer.
The final syntax for it to work is :

```
AMOUNT= sel.Sum(s => (decimal?)s["AMOUNT"])
```